# Is there a way for global-ignores to indicate a specific file, or a file name pattern only in a specific directory?

Tags: svn

I have a file that I don't want to delete, but doesn't belong in the repo. I don't want to commit an ignore property for it so as not to impact other users who may not want it ignored if they have it on their system. I don't want to just not commit the ignore since it just bothers me having to go out of my way to ignore the ignore prop.

I played with the global-ignores in the config file and I can ignore it by name, ie: `file.txt` but what about the day when I have another file named file.txt that I don't want ignored? so I tried feeding a path name to it, like so: `folder/file.txt` and since I'm on windows `folder\file.txt` and thinking maybe there is some sort of regex happening `folder\\file.txt`

None of that seems to work, even if I take it all the way to drive letter `c:\repo\folder\file.txt` using slashes, backslashes, or escaped backslashes.

So is there any way to reference an ignore on this file specifically without using the properties?

Also, the docs refer to these patters as "whitespace-delimited globs", glob in this sense is a new term for me, can anyone shed some light on the definition? Google is not my friend here considering the many non-IT definitions available for glob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through things one at a time:

Ignoring something is just a way to help you not to accidently put something in the repository you don't want in the repository. It can be *global* in nature or only local to a particular directory.

Ignoring something in Subversion does two things:

- It won't be listed when you do a `svn status`
- It won't be added if you do a `svn add *`

That's pretty much it. In fact, ignoring only works for files ***not*** in your repository. You can't ignore a file that's been added in your repository.

#### Why would you want to globally ignore something?

Let's say I do C development. I take files that have the *.c suffix, and they compile into files with the *.o suffix. I don't want these *.o files in my directory, so I set a global ignore.

#### Why would you want to ignore something in only a single directory?

Let's say if I build and execute a program, it creates a file called `output.txt` in my directory. I don't want that added to my repository, so I set the `svn:ignore` in that directory to *ignore* that file.

I build stuff with Maven, and Maven creates a *target* directory, In all of my Maven projects, I tell Subversion to ignore that *target* directory.

What does *whitespace-delimited globs* mean?

Globbing is a cheap and simple form of regular-expression like syntax. You probably use it all the time. It's mainly used on the command line. This is using globbing:

```
$ ls *.txt
```

So all *whitespace-delimited globs* mean are a bunch of *glob* expression such as above that you want to ignore no matter where it is. You separate them by white space and not by commas:

Right:

```
global-ignores="*.o *~ *.class"
```

Wrong:

```
global-ignores="*.o, *~, *.class"
```

One more thing, globs (i.e. file specifications) in ignores (whether global or by `svn:ignore`) cannot have directory prefixes. You can't globally ignore directories, but you can `svn:ignore` a directory. For example, I use Maven, and it builds everything under a directory called *target*. I can setup a `svn:ignore` on the target directory.

So, getting back to your question. If everyone has this file, but no one should add it to Subversion, then it should be ignored in that directory. All that will do is prevent someone from accidently adding it to Subversion. It won't hide it from their view.

If fact, in the end, you can ignore the ignore. You can commit and add files by simply specifying them even if you've previously said to ignore them.

If you really really want to make sure you don't accidentally commit files that shouldn't be committed, you should use my [pre-commit](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) trigger. This allows you to specify what shouldn't be committed and where. You can use globbing syntax or regular expression syntax. For example:

```
[file Don't allow people to add foo files to the bar directory]
file=**/bar/foo.*
access=no-add
users=@ALL

[file Don't allow people to add bar files to the foo directory]
match=/bar/foo.*$
access=no-add
users=@ALL
```

The first is set via a *glob*. The second is set via *regular expression*.

Hopes this answers your questions.

Comment: It does and doesn't. There's a lot of good info and suggestions in there, which I am grateful for so +1 there. But it seems that what I want to do exactly is not possible, or if it is, I am no closer to being able to do it than I was before. On another note, you say "You can't globally ignore directories" which I guess is true for a specific directory, but by having a glob of `dirName` I was able to globally ignore any directory with that name, which kind of gave me false hope I could specify paths.

Comment: What I said goes: You can't set global-ignores to ignore directories. These are mainly for the debris that gets created during the development process: Compiled objects, backup files, etc. Or maybe you can globally-ignore a directory -- I never tried it, but that's not what global-ignores are for. You can set a `svn:ignore` for directories, and for specific files. This is really what you want to do, if I understand your situation. However, it doesn't guarantee that these won't be committed to the repository. The only way to do that is to use a pre-commit hook.